# How can I send a wave towards something and have it respond with a specific value?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, signal-processing

Imagine a bat, for example. It uses its echo-location to send waves which get reflected back and thus return information about the surroundings. I want to do the same thing, but instead of just telling me there is a wall there, I want to return a number that I have "written" on the wall.

Suppose that I "write" the number 5 on the wall. How would I need to "write" the number 5 on the wall so that I can send some type of EM wave towards it and receive the number 5 in response?

Constraints/Assumptions:

1. Whatever is done to the wall cannot be battery powered.
2. There is nothing that can interfere with the travelling wave.
3. The wave can be of any type in the electromagnetic spectrum.
4. There will be other things "written" on other walls, so the wave will need to be able to distinguish from other "writings". If I "write" a 5 on one wall and a 6 on another, I need to be able to tell them apart. There can be $n$ number of writings on each wall, within some reasonable limit as defined by the solution.

**Edit:** - I noticed that most of the suggestions imply visible light. Although this is technically possible, I was hoping for something that was undetectable to the human eye/ear. For example, the RFID tag is more along the lines of what I was looking for. Basically, I need to send a signal and receive a signal back where the returning signal has a uniquely identifying value.

Comment: Can you choose what the wall's made of? And make the writing larger than several times the wavelength of your EM wave?

Comment: Yes and yes @ThePhoton

Comment: So make the wall concrete, and "write" with aluminum foil. The rest is "just engineering".

Comment: Or if you want the number 5 instead of the figure "5", then google RFID.

Comment: If you paint the number 5 on the wall then shine visible light on it, you get the number 5 back. All you need is for the colour of the paint to contrast with the colour of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

The high-tech way to make a return wave 'do what you want' is to
make a hologram.   A wall-hanging photographic plate, illuminated
by a monochromatic light source from a given direction, can
reproduce a monochrome image, in three dimensions, of anything
you choose to pose for the initial photographic exposure.

Light from off-target will generally only reveal a blur,
and light of a different color might give a distorted (larger
or smaller) image.   Multiple exposures with different
light sources can make multiple images onto a single surface,
each becoming distinct only with its associated reference
light source location and color.

Answer (score 0):

you could paint the number on the wall with ultraviolet paint, and the detector would be an ultraviolet detector.

Or you could use ultrasound as detector and the number in a material that has high ultrasonic refraction.